# how to loop using Redshift stored procedures

Tags: amazon-web-services, stored-procedures, amazon-redshift

I have lookup table that contains databasename and tablename with indicators. I want to loop through each table first to check for duplicates and if found will have to do some clean up.

```sql
CREATE or replace PROCEDURE sPtest()
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
DECLARE
        rec record;  
        tbl_nm varchar(40);
BEGIN
    FOR rec in select db_nm,tbl_nm from tmp_tbl_Lookup where dupcheck_ind <> 'Y' LOOP 
        RAISE INFO  'my table lists to be processed are: %', rec.tbl_nm;
    END LOOP;
END;
$$;

call sPtest()
SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: too many parameters specified for RAISE
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is in line

```
RAISE INFO  'my table lists to be processed are: %', rec.tbl_nm;
```

Read the error it says

```
SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: too many parameters specified for RAISE
```

maybe `rec.tbl_nm`   is  returning column of multiple values and you are using only one `%` for displaying all of the contents of the column

**Check if**

```
select db_nm,tbl_nm, count(*) as row_count from tmp_tbl_Lookup where dupcheck_ind <> 'Y'
```

`row_count` is  greater than 1